# Android Studio: Lint checks for Jack compiler

Tags: android-studio, android-lint, jack-compiler

Android Studio reports this Lint error when I use try-with-resources:

```
Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 17)
```

This reports is wrong: since I use the Jack compiler, I can use this feature also for older API versions (at least it works in the Emulator).

I could of course suppress this lint check with `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` but when we ever stop using the Jack compiler, this would be very bad.

So what should we do?

- is this some problem that needs to be reported to some issue tracking?
  e.g. should we report to Android Studio, or to Jack-compiler or is there some issue tracker for the Android lint checks?
- can we somehow globally deactivate this lint check automatically, when the Jack compiler is active?
- any other ideas...